# Implications of inequalities involving joint probabilities on the marginals

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the events $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2,  C_1, C_2, D_1, D_2, E_1, E_2, F_1, F_2,$ and the following inequalities
$$
Pr(E_1\cap F_1)\leq Pr(A_1\cap B_1)\leq Pr(C_1\cap D_1)
$$
$$
Pr(E_1\cap F_2)\leq Pr(A_1\cap B_2)\leq Pr(C_1\cap D_2)
$$
$$
Pr(E_2\cap F_1)\leq Pr(A_2\cap B_1)\leq Pr(C_2\cap D_1)
$$
$$
Pr(E_2\cap F_2)\leq Pr(A_2\cap B_2)\leq Pr(C_2\cap D_2)
$$

Also, $\sum_{i,j}Pr(A_i\cap B_j)=1$, $\sum_{i}Pr(A_j\cap B_i)=Pr(A_j)$, $\sum_{j}Pr(A_j\cap B_i)=Pr(B_i)$.

I am looking for implications of the above inequalities on
$$
Pr(A_1), Pr(A_2), Pr(B_1), Pr(B_2)
$$

I can see only that, since $Pr(A_1\cap B_1)+Pr(A_1\cap B_2)=Pr(A_1)$, then
$$
Pr(E_1\cap F_1)+Pr(E_1\cap F_2)\leq Pr(A_1)\leq Pr(C_1\cap D_1)+Pr(C_1\cap D_2)
$$
and similarly for $Pr(A_2), Pr(B_1), Pr(B_2)$.

Do you see other implications?

Comment: Your notation $Pr(A, B)$ is what everyone else denotes by $Pr(A\cap B)$ ? If so you might consider changing your notation

Comment: Yes, I'll change it. Thanks

Comment: By continuing your logic, you can achieve $\sum_{i,j} {Pr\left(E_i \cap F_j\right)} \le 1 \le \sum_{i,j} {Pr\left(C_i \cap D_j\right)}$, and using some union bounds, $ Pr\left(\bigcup_{i,j} A_i \cap B_j \right) \le Pr\left(A_1 \cup A_2\right) \le 1$ and $Pr\left(F_i \cap \left(E_1 \cup E_2\right) \right) \le Pr\left(B_i\right)$. Hopefully it'll help someone achieve a more complete solution.